# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'select'

Tags: python-3.x, select, tensorflow, deep-learning

Here is a simple deep learning program:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A = 3
B = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])
C = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 1, 1, 1])
D = tf.convert_to_tensor([0, 0, 0, 0])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.select(A > 1, 'A', 'B')))
    print(sess.run(tf.select(False, 'A', 'B')))
    print(sess.run(tf.select(B > 2, C, D)))
```

when I run it, am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'select'.

So, what should I do next?Are there any functions that could repalce tf.select?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.select` is deprecated since v0.12 and was renamed to [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) in v1.0 to match the naming of numpy. It's mentioned in the [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md).